# Error Request Mail

Tags: c#, envio-de-email, asp.net-core

Alguém poderia me dar um help aqui?
Estou fazendo uma verificação de ambientes para poder enviar um certo email, só que está dando o seguinte erro.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Poderiam me dizer como resolvo isso? meu codigo está abaixo

```
public void NovoEventoAdverso(int patientId, int hospitalId, int usuarioId)
{
    var cadastroRepository = new CadastroRepository();
    var investigadorRepository = new UsuarioRepository();
    var randomizacaoRepository = new RandomizacaoRepository();

    var paciente = cadastroRepository.GetByPatientId(patientId, hospitalId);
    var investigador = investigadorRepository.GetbyId(usuarioId);
    var randomizacao = randomizacaoRepository.GetByPatientId(patientId, hospitalId);

    var isHomolog = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("homolog") || Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("localhost") ? true : false;


    MailMessage objEmail = FactoryMailMessage();

    objEmail.To.Add("AAAA BBBB <CCCC@DDDD.com.br>");

    objEmail.Subject = $"Novo Evento Adverso - {paciente.inpac}";

    var conteudo = "Novo Evento Adverso cadastrado:<br />";
    conteudo += $"Iniciais do Paciente: {paciente.inpac}<br />";
    conteudo += $"Nome do Investigador: {investigador.Nome}<br />";
    conteudo += $"Data da Randomização: {randomizacao.RandomizacaoData.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")}<br />";
    conteudo += $"Data do Preenchimento: {DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")}";

    objEmail.Body = conteudo;

    EnviarEmail(objEmail);
}
```

Comment: Tenta assim => HttpContext.Request

Comment: Não funcionou
Esta parte do Request.Url .... eu tirei do meu index pois utilizei para fazer uma validação na visualização do meu ambiente. E estou tentando implementar no meu Email.cs para poder enviar um certo email depenendo do ambiente

Comment: Se os emails são diferentes, você não pode fazer 1 método para cada email?

Comment: Os emais não são diferentes, só que no meu caso eu preciso fazer uma verificação para ver qual o ambiente que um formulario foi cadastrando.
Porque é o seguinte se um formulario for cadastrado eu recebo um email avisando, só que preciso idenficar de onde esse formulario foi cadastrado, se foi de homologação ou se foi de produção deu pra entender?

Comment: Não, mas você pode passar essa verificação como um BOOLEANO por parâmetro para o método, não pode?

Comment: O erro já diz, Request não existe no seu contexto. Você referenciou (using ...) o assembly correto?

Comment: @GabrielColetta Eu não consigo importar nenhum using no cs referente a este Request

Comment: digo você referenciar esse Assembly na classe onde seu método `NovoEventoAdverso`  esta. O HttpContext precisa do system.web que se encontra nos pacotes asp.net. Se você estiver em uma camada sem essa dll não vai funcionar mesmo.

Comment: você está trabalhando com asp.net core?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo Sim estou